# Logout not working on browser close, with multiple tab opened

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I am doing a SAML based authentication and want my user to be logged out of the system in case he closes the browser: I have written the following browser side code:

```
window.onbeforeunload =function(e){

deleteAllCookies();

var my_form=document.createElement('FORM');
my_form.name='my_form';
my_form.method='POST';
my_form.action="sessionExpired.do";

var hiddenText=document.createElement('INPUT');
hiddenText.type='HIDDEN';
hiddenText.name='crash';
hiddenText.ID='crash';
hiddenText.value='yes';
my_form.appendChild(hiddenText);

my_form.submit();

return;


};
```

This code calls my logout service and able to logg out of the system, in case one tab is opened, but the same doesn't work if along with my application multiple other tabs are opened.i.e in case of multiple tab, my server code gets called which invalidates session, but still session remains logged in and is not asked for authentication again.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to what you can do in a handler for `beforeunload`.

You can return text to prompt the user to ask if they're sure they want to leave.
But, you cannot force the window to stay open long enough to make the request to the server.

- If you don't return a string, then the window will close immediately, and your form submission will not get processed.
- If you do return a string, then the user will be asked if they're sure they want to close the window.  If yes, the window will be closed, and your form submission will not get processed.  If no, then the window will not be closed.

Deleting the cookies will probably work, but I don't think it will be possible to submit the form, or make a request to the server when the window is closed.

Comment: form submission is happening and its deleting the cookie, but you are right if I return a string in that case form submission don't happen but server call is happening, I don't want the server to return back anything so if the server invalidates the session on call its fine forme, and code works well when one tab is opened but create problem in case of multiple tab.